# Session data added in Helper class but the data is not fetched by HttpContextAccessor .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Session data added in Helper class but the data is not fetched by HttpContextAccessor .net core
what should I do ? I have done DI too
Helper.cs
` private readonly  IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
private  ISession _sessionContext => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

```
    public Helper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    
    public string GetFromSession()
    {
        var S_code = _sessionContext.GetString("SessionCode");
        return S_code;
    }`
```

ClientDBConn.cs

```
            `Helper helper = new Helper();                //doesnt take this statement. hench error
            string clientc = Helper.GetFromSession();    //error in this 
           `
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add a services to your Startup.cs page, something as shown below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

      services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Then add set get session in helper class.

```
 public class MyHelper
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

        public MyHelper(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            this.accessor = accessor;
        }
        public string GetSession()
        {
            var httpContext = accessor.HttpContext;
            string S_code = httpContext.Session.GetString("SessionCode");

            return S_code;
        }

        public void SetSession()
        {
            var httpContext = accessor.HttpContext;
            httpContext.Session.SetString("SessionCode","ABC");

        }
    }
```

Comment: i already have added the services and all yet it is not getting the data.

Comment: @PramitManShrestha: This works perfectly for me. Check properly method GetSession() where I create an object 1st and later use it further

Comment: i haven't added SetSession as it is already there in my controller. I just need to get the session's data.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MultiTenantCoreMVC.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @PramitManShrestha: Have you tried , exactly what I have mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: yes i have . yet it is not getting the session's value from the controller to Helper class/ Context Class